# Efficient search for a prime factor of a very large number

Tags: functional-programming, prime-factoring

I search a prime factor of the huge number

3^(3^(3^3))+2^(2^(2^2))

The number is too large to apply elliptic curve method or even pollard-rho because it has about 3.6 * 10^12 digits. But it has a special form (the
first power has a very large and special exponent).

> How can I efficiently search for a prime factor of the given number ? 
>   Is trial division the only feasible method ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's primarily (har) a question about mathematics, not programming. A question about *implementing* a factorization technique might be appropriate here, but asking for the technique is more of a topic for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's an interesting question, but yeah, it's a little too open-ended for this site.

Comment: You can join in for a prime factor search here : https://github.com/gnufinder/prime-factor